# Disable F3 and F4 shortcuts

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut

I'd like to use my F3 and F4 keys for a different purpose, but I can't seem to disable the hotkeys on my Mac. Here's what I've tried so far:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set the Keyboard preference to Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys?

Comment: I haven't because I'd like all of the other F keys to function as they normally do

Comment: I don't think it's possible to re-define the special features keys individually. You can press the fn key to shift between special keys and function keys, though.

Comment: hmm i had it working on my old macbook. i just dont remember what i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remap-macs-function-keys-anything-want/

/10char

Comment: This site disfavors link-only answers, because links die over time. Better is to include the link (so readers can see where the info is coming from) and also to select, copy, and paste the relevant information text directly into your answer. Do that using the fat "quote marks" icon in the composition/edit box. This also has the advantage that the substance of the answer is searchable, and is machine-readable for sight-impaired users.